# How do you get a list of filenames from a URL?

Tags: string-manipulation, interoperability, web-access

How would I get a list of filenames available at a URL? For example, list the files at:

http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/

Comment: i know javascript :  document.getElementsByTagName('a').length - 4                 removed 4 because of parent directory ,and 4 label links

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Does this do the job?

```
links = Import[
    "http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/",
    "Hyperlinks"]

 {"http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/?C=N;O=D",
  "http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/?C=M;O=A",
  "http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/?C=S;O=A",
  ...
```

then you can cherry-pick the ones you want using, eg,`StringCases`:

```
DeleteCases[StringCases[links, __ ~~ "gif"], {}]

{{"http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/pdi20050416-pg.gif"}, 
 {"http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/pdi20050423-pg.gif"}, 
 {"http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/pdi20050430-pg.gif"}, 
 {"http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/pdi20050507-pg.gif"}, ...
```

Comment: Much easier than mine :)  I am sure that I looked through the docs of Import and couldn't find a reference to "Hyperlinks".  If I had, I wouldn't have gone down the R route.

Comment: It does return some links that aren't files though such as "http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/?C=N;O=D"

Comment: @WalkingRandomly True, but that's easily fixed.

Answer (score 7):

As is commonly recommended in other Q&As for tasks such as this, we can also use `Cases`:

```
baseurl = "http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/";
source = Import[baseurl, "XMLObject"];
baseurl <> # & /@ Rest@Cases[source, XMLElement["td", __,
     {XMLElement["a", __, {___ ..., c_, ___ ...}]}
     ] :> c, Infinity]
```

> {"http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/pdi20050101.wkly",
>   "http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/pdi20050108.wkly",
>   "http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/pdi20050115.wkly",
>   "http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/pdi20050122.wkly",...

Or just remove `baseurl <> # & /@` if you don't want the full URLs, but only the file names.

Answer (score 6):

Although I am sure that this can be done in Mathematica, I already know how to do it in R.  For example, see the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930933/retrieve-the-list-of-files-from-a-url

Thanks to RLink, I can use this solution directly in Mathematica

```
(*Initialise R*)
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR[]
(*Install the XML package*)
REvaluate["install.packages('XML')"]
rdata = REvaluate["
   {
   library(XML)
   readHTMLTable(\"http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/\
weekly-palmers/2005/\", 
                 skip.rows=1:2)[[1]]$Name -> file.list
   }
   "];
filenames = DeleteCases[RFactorToVector[rdata], _Missing];
```

Lets look at the first 10 filenames:

```
In[98]:= filenames[[1 ;; 10]]

Out[98]= {"pdi20050101.wkly", "pdi20050108.wkly", "pdi20050115.wkly", \
"pdi20050122.wkly", "pdi20050129.wkly", "pdi20050205.wkly", \
"pdi20050212.wkly", "pdi20050219.wkly", "pdi20050222.wkly", \
"pdi20050226.wkly"}
```

Comment: +1. I do anticipate though more flames from Mac users, for the `install.packages` part, and they would be right ...

Comment: Completely! Is the Mac version of Mathematica any cheaper? I guess it should be if there is less functionality

Comment: This was just very unfortunate - this was probably the single most important flaw that I didn't have the time to fix. I do hope to have the time to address this for the next version, though.

Comment: I didn't realize that RLink was your work! It really is very, very nice.  Any chance of a Python Link?

Comment: Re:RLink - thanks! Particularly great to hear it from you, given your very diverse background and interests in computational math tools and languages. There are tons of things it currently lacks, of course, but it has been a cool project. Re: PythonLink - not currently, alas, but possibly in the future. My own thinking is that the more links we have the better. That would allow one to exploit Mathematica as a hub for multi-language development, the role which IMO would suit it very well, and a direction which has been so far largely unexplored, particularly in the industry sector.

Comment: +1 for 'more links the better' - Since I work with so many different languages and systems, I often find myself in the position of knowing how to do something easily in one language but not in another. Another use-case is when you have fully working code in another language and you just want to use it as a black box in Mathematica or wrap a Manipulate around it or whatever.

Comment: 'fully working code in another language' - yep, totally agree. Mathematica can be a nice high-level interface to test and glue code written in a number of different languages, and add extra level of interactivity.

Answer (score 0):

I like this way. It's similar to @Anon but with simpler `Cases` syntax:

```
baseurl="http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/";
source=Import[baseurl,"XMLObject"];
files=Cases[source,{_,"href"->file_/;StringMatchQ[file,"*.*"]}:> file ,\[Infinity]];
baseurl<>#&/@files
```

And you could easily choose file format, using for example `"*.gif"` instead of `"*.*"`